# OS rescan disk after DD write command

Tags: automount, dd

When I executed "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=1" (sda is a SATA device), when the command was done. And the OS will rescan the disk, looks like try to scan the partition information. Do you know if there is any method can disable the auto scan operation?

Thanks,
Billy

Comment: Was this disk mounted during the `dd` command execution?

Comment: No. It is raw disk

Answer (score 0):

The issue disappeared when udev service was stopped, but I don't know why running `dd` would trigger udev to scan the disk.

```
service udev stop
service udev start
```